# Read text file in C# and send the data to mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new here and I need some help. Hope you guys can solve my problem.

I have successfully created a windows service that sends data from the server (time and date stamp) by using timer. the only thing that prevents me from doing this is the text file. I want to use the data on the text file as my "where command" under the mysql command.

see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace bicmwinservice
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug() 
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        private Timer count;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            count = new Timer(1 * 60 * 1000);  // 5 minutes expressed as milliseconds
            count.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
            count.AutoReset = true;
            count.Start();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");          
        }

        private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
        {


                DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;


                string connString = "Server=mysql1003.mochahost.com;Database=snowphil_tester;Uid=snowphil_test;password=snowphil_test;";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
                MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();


                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\brcode.txt", Encoding.Default);

                command.CommandText = "Update branch_monitor SET `date`='" + date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + "', `time`= '" + time.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss") + "' WHERE branch_code='" + read + "'";
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

if I replace the WHERE="" with current data that I want. the code is working and it sends data on the server.

Thanks guys! happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace bicmwinservice
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug() 
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        private Timer count;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            count = new Timer(1 * 60 * 1000);  // 5 minutes expressed as milliseconds
            count.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
            count.AutoReset = true;
            count.Start();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");          
        }

        private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
        {


                DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;


                string connString = "Server=mysql1003.mochahost.com;Database=snowphil_tester;Uid=snowphil_test;password=snowphil_test;";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
                MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

                string read = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\brcode.txt");


                command.CommandText = "Update branch_monitor SET `date`='" + date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + "', `time`= '" + time.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss") + "' WHERE branch_code='" + read + "'";
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mostafizur! I really appreciate your quick response on this but the code didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention, the code did not read the text inside the text file. The text inside the text file is 0099. Thanks!

Comment: but I have tested the text reading code just now, and working here fine, debug your program and watch if `read` variable have any value or not,  is your `branch_code`  is a  `int` type in db ?

Comment: The branch_code is in Varchar. Thanks I'll try to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1. Does you source file have multiple lines? i.e.

   ```
   0099
   0100
   0101
   ```
2. OR is it 2 lines with an empty second line? If so, you'll actually be getting

   ```
   0099\n
   ```

Solutions:

1. Mulitple lines

   ```
   foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\brcode.txt"))
   {
       [your sql connection code]
       "... WHERE branch_code='" + line + "';"
   }
   ```
2. Maybe you just need to trim the newlines if you only expect a single line in the source file:

   ```
   string line = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\brcode.txt").Trim();
   ```

Comment: Hi Grinknok! I only have one line on my source. I tried both but no luck. Thanks you!

Comment: Hi Griknok! It worked! what I did is i transferred the text file on the other drive which is D: and it worked!! Big thanks to you and to Moztafizur also.